# Find uppercase letters within <p></p> tags using regex

Tags: html, regex, visual-studio-2010

I want to use a regular expression to grab ONLY uppercase characters within a `<p></p>` html tag.

`<p>I WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</p>`

`<p>I don't want to get this text because it has some Lower Case Characters</p>`

Sometimes the document doesn't contain this at all. Sometimes it's there 3-5 times. The document DOES contain other HTML within `<p></p>` tags which I don't want to change. Only the paragraph tags which contain ALL Uppercase characters I want to return.

I not very familiar with regular expressions so this is stumping me. It seems like I should be able to do something like this: `<p>[A-Z]</p>`

Once I find the uppercase text, I want to pass the data through a ProperCase function and re-insert the data as a `<H3>` tag.

Comment: are you really looking to do this in Visual Studio itself, or within  language that VS supports?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(<p>)([^a-z]+)(</p>)
```

This evaluates to:

- **true** for `<p>I WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</p>`
- **true** for `<p>I DON'T WANT TO GET MIXED CASE TEXT 123.</p>`
- **false** for `<p>I don't want to get this text because it has some Lower Case Characters</p>`

Answer (score 0):

well I am not familiar with visual-studio. but you can use the regex below:

```
(?<=<p>)[A-Z ]*(?=</p>)
```

testing with grep:

```
kent$  echo "<p>I WANT TO GET THIS TEXT</p>"|grep -Po '(?<=<p>)[A-Z ]*(?=</p>)'
```

**output**

```
I WANT TO GET THIS TEXT
```

if there are some small letters:

```
kent$  echo "<p>BIGBIG BIG and some small letters</p>"|grep -Po '(?<=<p>)[A-Z ]*(?=</p>)'

(output nothing)
```